# Find groups that are missing values of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hopefully someone can send some light on an issue I'm trying to resolve.

**Types**

```
Type 
------
'Type1'
'Type2'
'Type3'
```

**Codes**

```
Code |  ID  | Type
---------------------
ABC  | 1234 | 'Type1'
ABC  | 1234 | 'Type2'
CDE  | 2345 | 'Type1'
CDE  | 2345 | 'Type3'
EFG  | 3456 | 'Type2'
```

I would like to be able to determine those Code/ID pairs that are missing a particular type.
The result of this query should yield.

```
Code |  ID  | Type
--------------------
ABC  | 1234 | 'Type3'
CDE  | 2345 | 'Type2'
EFG  | 3456 | 'Type1'
EFG  | 3456 | 'Type3'
```

Comment: I don't think thisis possible with plain SQL

Comment: @RedGuy11 you think so?

Comment: Where is the complete list of all <Code, ID> pairs? Without that, your goal is impossible. You have one suggestion which **assumes** the complete list is simply all distinct pairs in your table. Is that safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation for this:

```sql
SELECT
    c.Code,
    c.ID,
    t.Type
FROM Types t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM Codes c
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN c.Type = T.Type THEN 1 END) ) AS v (IsMatch)
    GROUP BY Code, ID
    HAVING COUNT(IsMatch) = 0
) c;
```

Another option is to cross join the possible IDs with the Types, then `EXCEPT` to remove the existing ones. Problem is, this means scanning the table twice:

```sql
SELECT
    c.Code,
    c.ID,
    t.Type
FROM Types t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Code, ID
    FROM Codes c
) c
EXCEPT
SELECT
    c.Code,
    c.ID,
    c.Type
FROM Codes c;
```

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface - first query complains about multiple columns being specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. Second query works well.

Comment: Fixed that. I think the first query is better due to only one scan.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
select Code,  ID , Type 
from youtable 
where 'Type' = '' or `Type` IS NULL
```

or this?

```
select Code,  ID , t.typeid
from youtable y
left join Types t on y.typeid = t.typeid
where t.typeid IS NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Charlieface: Why not? Do you believe it’s an incorrect answer? If so, what is the contributor missing? Offering constructive feedback will help them improve their answer, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I usually approach this using a `CROSS JOIN` to generate all combinations and the `LEFT JOIN` (or `NOT EXISTS` to remove those that exist:

```
SELECT c.Code, c.ID, t.Type
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code, Id FROM Codes c
     ) c CROSS JOIN
     Types t LEFT JOIN
     codes
     ON codes.id = c.id AND codes.type = t.type
WHERE codes.code IS NULL;
```

If you have a separate list of codes (which you should have), then you can use that instead of the `SELECT DISTINCT`.